# wrt dataframes, what's the R equivalent to SQL's "Select From Where" structure?

Tags: r

I have an R dataframe (called DataTable) with two columns: Value and Gender. Value is numeric and Gender is M or F.

If the dataframe were a table in SQL I could say:

Select * from DataTable where Gender = 'M'

What's the best way to express this in R? I'd like the output to be just a vector of the values where Gender = M.

I've tried doing:

```
A <- DataTable[, Gender == "M"]
```

but it doesn't work. Here's what I get:

```
> A
```

data frame with 0 columns and 26 rows

```
> str(A)
```

'data.frame':   26 obs. of  0 variables

```
> summary(A)
```

< table of extent 0 x 0 >

Also, I'm trying to follow Google's R style guide and it says to never use the attach function, so I'd like to know how to do this without using it.

I've browsed The R Cookbook and also The R Book for this answer but didn't find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: If DataTable is a `data.frame`, you need `A <- DataTable[DataTable$Gender == "M",]`.

Comment: You want a vector? Which column you want to select then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you put `Gender == "M"` into the wrong side of the `[,]`, that is the columns side, e.g. `DataTable[rows, columns]`, to select rows make it:

```
A <- DataTable[DataTable$Gender == "M",]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want `value` you would do in SQL

```
select value from DataTable where gender = 'M'
```

The equivalent in R would be

```
subset(DataTable, gender == "M", value)
```

or, using basic indexing operations only,

```
DataTable[DataTable$gender == "M", "value"]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback. I tried those suggestions and none of them worked...but here's why: I'm reading in the data from a CSV file. In the Gender column there's a space after the comma so I have to put ==" M" and not =="M". So after I do that all your suggestions work. Thanks so much everyone!